# Initialization just after tkinter's root.mainloop() has begun (Python)

Tags: python, callback, tkinter

With Python's `tkinter`, I know how to do something when both the program and `mainloop()` are about to being closed:

```
def quit():
   #blah

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", quit)

root.mainloop()
```

But now **I would like to do some initialization immediately after the mainloop() has started.**

```
def afterstartup():
    #blah

root.mainloop()
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`tkinter.Tk.after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method):

Below is a simple script to demonstrate:

```
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()

def afterstartup():
    print("hello")

# The number here is how many milliseconds to wait
root.after(1000, afterstartup)

root.mainloop()
```

One second after the main window appears, the script prints `hello` in the terminal.

Comment: Ok thanks! Do you also use that for your initializations ?
I have noticed that if I put certain initializations *before* `root.mainloop()`  it doesn't work properly because some elements aren't drawn / displayed yet... Have you noticed the same thing @iCodez ?

Comment: @Basj - Yes.  Usually, it is best to set everything up before the window is loaded (because doing anything afterwards slows the operation of the GUI).  However, some things can't be done until _after_ the window is loaded (because they require such things as the widgets being drawn).  To handle these, the `after` method is perfect.  Aside from being the cleanest solution, one of the primary reasons it was created was to handle initializations after calling `root.mainloop`.

Comment: @iCodez: Nice explanation—but an even better reason to do things beforehand if possible than speeding up the GUI is preventing it from rearranging itself which the user is watching (which is always user-unfriendly, whether it's so fast it's a flicker or so slow that it looks like your widgets have a life of their own).